Calling CAPTCHA component from sign in page but its not working properly in react js
I want to have a custom captcha component which I can call from any page whenever required. Currently i want to call this on click of signin button in sign in page. It needs to verify that captcha and only then proceed for sign in. I am new to react please help me.
My captcha looks like this:-
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { IoMdRefresh } from "react-icons/io";

const generateRandomText = () => {
  const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  return _.sampleSize(characters, 6).join(''); // Generate a 6-character random string
};

const Captcha  = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState(generateRandomText());
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState('');
  const [isVerified, setIsVerified] = useState(false);
  const canvasRef = React.createRef();

  const clearCanvas = (canvas) => {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  };

  const distortText = (text, canvas) => {
    clearCanvas(canvas);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = '#1D4ED8'; 
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Distort text
    ctx.font = '28px italic Arial';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff'; // White text
    
    const textArray = text.split('');
    const textWidth = ctx.measureText(text).width;
    const charWidth = textWidth / textArray.length;
    
    textArray.forEach((char, index) => {
      const x = canvas.width / 2 - textWidth / 2 + index * charWidth + (Math.random() * 5 - 2.5); // Random X offset
      const y = canvas.height / 2 + (Math.sin(index * 0.1) * 10); // Wavy Y offset
      ctx.font = `24px italic Arial`;
      ctx.fillStyle = `#ffffff`;
      ctx.fillText(char, x, y);
    });
    
    // Add random black lines above text
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(Math.random() * canvas.width, Math.random() * canvas.height);
      ctx.lineTo(Math.random() * canvas.width, Math.random() * canvas.height);
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000'; // Black lines
      ctx.lineWidth = Math.random() * 2 + 1; // Random line width
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  };

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setUserInput(e.target.value);
  };


  const verify = () => {
    if (userInput === text) {
      setIsVerified(true);
      return true;
    } else {
      setIsVerified(false);
      return false;
    }
  };

  const refreshCaptcha = () => {
    setText(generateRandomText());
    setUserInput('');
    setIsVerified(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (canvasRef.current) {
      distortText(text, canvasRef.current);
    }
  }, [text]);

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center">
      <div className="flex justify-center mb-4">
        <canvas
          ref={canvasRef}
          width={150}
          height={50}
          className="mr-3 rounded-md "
          alt="Captcha Image"
        />
        <div className="flex items-center"> 
          <IoMdRefresh 
            onClick={refreshCaptcha} 
            style={{ fontSize: '18px', color: 'black' }} 
            className="mr-4"
          />
        </div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={userInput}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          className="p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Captcha;

My sign in page looks like this:-
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  signInStart,
  signInSuccess,
  signInFailure,
} from "../redux/User/userSlice.js";
import BG from "../assets/BG.jpg";
import Captcha from '../components/Captcha.jsx'

export default function SignIn() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const { loading, error } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
    });
  };



  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

      dispatch(signInStart());
      await axios.post("/api/auth/signin", formData)
      .then(function (response) {
        dispatch(signInSuccess(response));
        navigate("/profile");
      })
      .catch(function (error){
        dispatch(signInFailure(error.response?.data?.message));
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
    <div
      className="bg-cover bg-center h-screen justify-center  bg-no-repeat"
      style={{ "backgroundImage": `url(${BG})` }}
    >
    <div className="flex min-h-full flex-col justify-center px-6 py-12 lg:px-8">
      <div className="sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-sm mt-20">
        <h2 className="mt-10 text-center text-2xl font-bold leading-9 tracking-tight text-blue-700">
          Log in to your account
        </h2>
      </div>

      <div className="mt-10 sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-sm">
        <form
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          className="space-y-6"
        >
          <div>
            <label
              htmlFor="username"
              className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
            >
              Username
            </label>
            <div className="mt-2">
              <input
                id="username"
                name="username"
                type="text"
                autoComplete="username"
                required
                placeholder="Username"
                onChange={handleChange}
                className="block w-full rounded-md border-0 p-2.5 text-left text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-blue-700 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div>
            <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
              <label
                htmlFor="password"
                className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
              >
                Password
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-2">
              <input
                id="password"
                name="password"
                type="password"
                autoComplete="current-password"
                required
                placeholder="Password"
                onChange={handleChange}
                className="block w-full rounded-md border-0  p-2.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-blue-700  sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <Captcha />
          {error && (
            <p className="text-red-500 mt-5 text-center text-xl">{error}</p>
          )}
          <div>
            <button
              type="submit"
              disabled={loading}
              className="flex w-full justify-center rounded-md bg-blue-700  px-3 p-2.5 text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-blue-500 disabled:opacity-70 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-blue-700 "
            >
              {loading ? "Loading..." : "Sign In"}
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
         
        <p className="mt-10 text-center text-sm text-gray-500">
          New User?
          <Link to="/sign-up">
            <span className="font-semibold leading-6 text-blue-700 hover:text-blue-500">
              Sign Up
            </span>
          </Link>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </>
  );
}


Please help
